# Get substring of characters up to the first occurance of dot or dash

Tags: php, regex, string

How do you specify that you want to return a substring containing all characters from the start of a string up to but not including the first dot or dash?

For example if the original string is:

```
'abcdefg.hij-k'
```

or if the original string is:

```
'abcdefg.hi-j.k.l.mn-op'
```

Then the same substring of:

```
'abcdefg'
```

should be returned.

The key thing here is that there may be multiple dots and dashes occurring randomly and we are only interested in the first chunk of characters.

EDIT:
A dot or a dash may occur first.

Comment: -Not a duplicate of the one mentioned

Comment: The answer to the duplicate question is to use explode. This is not the answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use preg_split:

```
$res = preg_split('/[-.]/', $string);
```

The string you want is in `$res[0]`

Or preg_match:

```
preg_match('/^([^-.]+)/', $string, $matches);
```

The result is in `$match[1]`

Answer (score -1):

Try using the [explode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
$final = explode(".", $originalstr);
```

first should be `$final[0];`